# Вывести структуру zip архива Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

у решил сделать одну задачу:

Выводить файловую структуру мы научились. Теперь на очереди — архивы.

Напишите программу, на вход которой поступает zip-архив с именем input.zip. Вам же требуется вывести на экран его файловую структуру.
Поскольку внутри архива может быть своя иерархия каталогов, то каждый уровень вложенности необходимо предварить двумя пробелами.

Если архив пустой, то ничего выводить на экран не требуется.

При обходе содержимого архива выводите файлы в том порядке, в котором вы их получаете.
Формат вывода
(_ - пробел)

1
__2
__3
____files
______123.txt
______libs
__4

Но я настолько запарился с этой задачей, что потерял все свои нервы.
В итоге у меня получилось это:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile


maindir = ''
filelist = []
finallist = ''
ok1 = False
ok = True


with ZipFile('input.zip') as myzip:
    dir = ''
    for name in myzip.namelist():
        ok = True
        while ok:
            if '/' in name:
                if maindir in name:
                    name = name.rstrip(maindir + '/')
                    name = '  ' + name
                    if '/' in name:
                        ok1 = True
                elif ok1:
                    maindir += name.split('/')[0]
                else:
                    maindir = name.split('/')[0]
            else:
                ok = False
                print(name)
```

Но ничего, к сожалению, не получилось. Можете помочь решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрезаем `/` в конце каждого полного имени. Бьём оставшуюся строку по `/`. Количество элементов в полученном списке минус один - это нужное количество отступов. Последний элемент - имя файла/директории для вывода на печать.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('input.zip') as myzip:
    for name in myzip.namelist():
        items = name.rstrip("/").split("/")
        print("  "*(len(items)-1) + items[-1])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!